# Why am I able to successfully get a lock multimple times in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a function (scala) that calls some MySQL sql: `SELECT GET_LOCK(‘foo’,5);`

If I call this funtion I get the expected return value of 1, success.
If I call this function again immediately, I also get 1 back.  I expected 0 since I had not explicitly released the lock.

Why am I getting 1 the second, and any subsequent calls?

Comment: That sounds like you're calling `get_lock()` from the same session multiple times.  As the session already has the lock, calling it again won't block the session.  Try opening two discrete sessions, then calling `get_lock()` in each session separately.  This is covered in the [online help](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html), which specifically states `The lock is exclusive. While held by one session, other sessions cannot obtain a lock of the same name.`  Pay careful attention to the words `other sessions`.

Comment: please show the code for your locks also did you chek the locks

Comment: Yes, MatBaili… I was doing this in the same session.  I’m using finagle, and they have a function to produce a new session from a client, and their docs call this feature out as being for the purpose of locks, transactions, and such.  Sadly, this is also giving me the same behavior—2 sessions still succeed on thensame named lock.  I’ve opened a separate question on that one.